# Relation of two commuting operators to other operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

Consider two commuting quantum operators:

$$\hat{A} \hat{B} = \hat{B} \hat{A} \quad $$

For any operator $\hat{C} $, how can we prove that:

$$\hat{A} \hat{C}  \hat{B} \hat{C} = \hat{B} \hat{C} \hat{A} \hat{C} \quad .$$

Comment: You can't as it is not generally true. Perhaps you were thinking of ${\rm tr}(ACB)={\rm tr}(BCA)$?

Comment: Let $A$ be the identity operator, the $A$ and $B$ will always commute but then your second expression reduces to asking if $B$ and $C$ commute

Comment: You have  edited  the question, The comments above apply to the old one. Your statement is still false though.

Answer (score 1):

Toy counterexample,
$$\hat{A}=\sigma_1, \qquad  \hat{B}={\mathbb I}, \qquad  \hat{C} = \sigma_2, \\
\hat{A} \hat{C}    \neq   \hat{C} \hat{A}    .$$